# MonoMac: Cant create a Merged Mono App Bundle

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, monomac

Another issue dealing with MonoMac. I cant even create a bundle, if I do so I get this error.

```
Creating app bundle
Contents/Info.plist
Contents/PkgInfo
Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib
Contents/Resources/MainWindow.nib
Contents/Resources/PrefForm.nib
Contents/Resources/SearchForm.nib
Contents/Resources/StreamInformation.nib
Contents/Resources/sd.icns
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/categories.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/cdecls.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/decls.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/files.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/imports.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/pbxindex.header
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/protocols.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/refs.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/subclasses.pbxbtree
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/symbols0.pbxsymbols
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/strings.pbxstrings/control
Contents/Resources/build/StreamDesk.build/StreamDesk.pbxindex/strings.pbxstrings/strings

Merging Mono into app bundle
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/mmp -o "/tmp/monomac-build-634642319384392990" -n "StreamDesk" -a "/Users/michaelmanley/Desktop/NasuTek-StreamDesk/libstreamdesk/Managed/StreamDesk.Core/bin/Debug/StreamDesk.Managed.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" -a "/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.Data.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" -a "/Users/michaelmanley/Desktop/NasuTek-StreamDesk/3rdParty/Mono.Addins.dll" "/Users/michaelmanley/Desktop/NasuTek-StreamDesk/StreamDesk-Cocoa/bin/Debug/StreamDesk.exe"
Could not link assemblies: System.ArgumentException: Member 'System.Int32 Mono.Addins.Database.SetupProcess::Main(System.String[])' is declared in another module and needs to be imported
  at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.LookupToken (IMetadataTokenProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<BuildMetadata>b__0 (Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder builder, Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader _) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[MetadataBuilder,MetadataBuilder] (Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder item, System.Func`3 read) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder metadata) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModuleTo (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, System.IO.StreamFailed to link /Users/michaelmanley/Desktop/NasuTek-StreamDesk/StreamDesk-Cocoa/bin/Debug/StreamDesk.exe
 stream, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.OutputAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.ProcessAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoMac.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
mmp exited with code 1

Merging Mono failed
```

I did include a build of Mono.Addins but theres nothing that even remotely calls such a function, and Im lost at why it WANTS that. Just not having a good day with Mono.

If you wanna have a shot the source code is at https://github.com/NasuTek/NasuTek-StreamDesk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, when I use the option "Don't Link Assemblies" it works all well.